# How to get CloudTrail to record user-data script in the log

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudtrail

I have users who will be able to submit scripts to instances via the `aws ec2 run-instances --user-data file://bla.sh` option.

I have setup CloudTrail to save almost all of the data that I need to log to an encrypted logging bucket that users don't have access to, including the run-instances events. I need to log the scripts themselves, but CloudTrail shows the following in the event log:

```
"userData": "<sensitiveDataRemoved>"
```

Is there any way to allow logging of the user-data through CloudTrail or a similar AWS service?

I can make a daemon which checks for user data on boot, and sends it to a bucket, but that means the assumed role that the instance is running with has write access to the logged scripts in the bucket. I prefer the CloudTrail-like solution that I have for the other logs, because the users don't have access to any of the logging events, or the logs themselves.

Cheers!

Comment: Since UserData can contain genuinely sensitive data, like (private) encryption keys, access tokens, clear text passwords and other secrets, the question arises if there really is pressing business requirement to get that data added to your centralised logs? Should you want to collect it in the first place? Regardless of what is technically feasible.

Comment: Thanks for asking. Currently, our usage case is the processing of data whose encryption, access, etc. is fully handled by KMS, and all IAM users have access to all data (except logs) within each account. This means there should be no actually sensitive info within the logs. The reason why the scripts need to be kept is because this data is GDPR sensitive, and we need to keep a record of who processes the data, and how it is processed. I can get the users to fill out a log each time they use it, but an automatic system is preferable.